# How can i print a rdfs label with Jena

Tags: jena, owl, ontology, rdfs

Hi i have create a new ontology for relate Drugs and diseases; now i query its for recovering the name of Drug related a particular disease.
My code is:

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
    FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader());
    Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("Drugs_Diseases.owl");
    String strQuery = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "+
                       "PREFIX des: <http://www.entrez.com/> "+
                       "SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?object "
                       + "WHERE {   "
                       + "?subject des:isDrugOfDisease ?object .  "
                       + "?object rdfs:label ?label . "
                       + "FILTER regex(str(?label), \"pain\") }";

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(strQuery);
    QueryExecution execQuery = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    try{
        ResultSet results = execQuery.execSelect();

        while(results.hasNext()){
            QuerySolution sol = results.nextSolution();
            RDFNode node = sol.get("subject");
            String stringPrint = node.asNode().toString();
            System.out.println(stringPrint);
        }
    } finally {
        execQuery.close();

}}
}
```

The results of this query is:

```
http://www.entrez.com/DAP000017
http://www.entrez.com/DAP000021
```

but my intent is to have:

```
Diazepam 
Dextropropoxyphene
```

in OWL i have:

```
 <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.entrez.com/DAP000021">
    <entrez:isDrugOfDisease>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="http://orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_#DIS_ID_75"/>
    </entrez:isDrugOfDisease>
    <entrez:id>DAP000021</entrez:id>
    <rdfs:label>Diazepam</rdfs:label>
  </owl:Class>
```

Answer (score 1):

SPARQL only returns what you select, thus, you have to select the label in the SPARQL query of course:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?drug ?disease ?drugLabel WHERE
 ?drug des:isDrugOfDisease ?disease .
 ?drug rdfs:label ?drugLabel .
 ?disease rdfs:label ?label . 
 FILTER regex(str(?label), \"pain\") 
}
```

In the code, get the label from the solution object:

```java
while(results.hasNext()){
        QuerySolution sol = results.nextSolution();
        RDFNode node = sol.get("drug");
        String stringPrint = node.asNode().toString();
        System.out.println(stringPrint);
        // label
        String label = sol.getLiteral("drugLabel").getLexicalForm();
        System.out.println(label);
}
```

Note, I changed the variable names. In general, it's easier to read and understand a query if you use meaningful names for the variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if i use your code the results are: 
pain
pain, anesthesia and anxiety

and not what I am looking for.
I want obtain for example: 
Diazepam and Dextropropoxyphene

Comment: Then you have to get the label of the subject indeed...I changed it in the answer. Note, your example is confusing resp. incomplete as doesn't match the query you have shown. That makes answers always difficult.

Comment: Yes, i want the label of the subject.
I'm sorry for confuse description this is my first question.

Comment: No worries, I hope I changed it correctly in the answer. It *should* work now, but untested as I don't have your data.